# Добавить новый текст из Entry во второй Label

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter

Ситуация такая: 
я создал несколько `Label` и один `Entry`,
но не могу придумать как добавлять каждый новый введенный текст в новый `Label` последовательно. 
Хочу сделать `TaskList`.

Я понимаю, что нужно проверять существует ли в первом `Label` текст и через `if` перебирать, но что именно писать - я не знаю. *Python 3.9*

```
from tkinter import *


def show_message():
    message2.set(message.get())
    message_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    if # Не могу понять, что писать дальше?



root = Tk()
root.title("GUI на Python")
root.configure(background='#333333')
root.geometry("600x600")

# MAIN FUNCS

message = StringVar()
message2 = StringVar()
message3 = StringVar()

message_label = Label(textvariable=message2, anchor="w",
                      background='#333333',
                      font="Arial 16",
                      fg="white")
message_label.place(width=400, x=110, y=20)

message_label2 = Label(textvariable=message3, anchor="w",
                      background='#333333',
                      font="Arial 16",
                      fg="white")
message_label2.place(width=400, x=110, y=50)

message_entry = Entry(textvariable=message,
                      font="Arial 16")
message_entry.place(width=520, x=10, y=550)

message_button = Button(text="Add", command=show_message,
                        font="Arial 16")
message_button.place(width=50, height=28, x=540, y=550)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("GUI на Python")
        self.root.configure(background='#333333')
        self.root.geometry("600x600")
        
        self.y = 20
        
        # MAIN FUNCS
        self.message = tk.StringVar()
        self.message_entry = tk.Entry(
            textvariable=self.message,
            font="Arial 16")
        self.message_entry.place(width=520, x=10, y=550)

        self.message_button = tk.Button(
            text="Add", 
            command=self.show_message,
            font="Arial 16")
        self.message_button.place(width=50, height=28, x=540, y=550)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_message(self):
        message2 = tk.StringVar()
        message_label = tk.Label(
            textvariable=message2, 
            anchor="w",
            background='#333333',
            font="Arial 16",
            fg="white"
        )
        message_label.place(width=400, x=110, y=self.y)

        message2.set(self.message.get())
        self.message_entry.delete(0, 'end')

        self.y += 30       

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=App()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрейший человек!!! XD Всех благ)

Comment: Я понял, что мне нужно нормально уже с классами разобраться, без ООП ловить нечего

Comment: @DmitryIgorevich пожалуйста, вы все правильно поняли.